# A problem on semicontinuous functions, open set

Tags: general-topology, real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space, and consider function $f:X \rightarrow R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty \} $, and given the following definitions

Lower semicontinuous: $$f(x) \leq \liminf\limits_{y\to x} f(y) = \sup\limits_{r>0} \inf\limits_{y\in B(x,r) \setminus \{x\}} \ f(y)$$

Upper semicontinuous: $$f(x) \geq \limsup\limits_{y\to x} f(y) = \inf\limits_{r>0} \sup\limits_{y\in B(x,r) \setminus \{x\}} \ f(y)$$

Then, let $\emptyset \ne U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ be open, and functions $g: U \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$ and $h: U \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$, and $a(x) < b(x), \forall x \in U$. Define $$W=\{(t,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times U | g(x) < t < h(x) \} $$
Prove $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ iff $g$ is upper semicontinuous and $h$ is lower semicontinuous.

---

Here is my thoughts:

1. Suppose $W$ is open, and $(t_0,x_0) \in W$, we have $g(x_0) < t_0$, and $\exists r >0 $ s.t. when $(t,x) \in B_r((t_0,x_0))$, we have $g(x) < t$. To prove $g$ is upper semicontinuous, I'd like to prove it by contradiction. Assume $$g(x_0) < \limsup\limits_{x\to x_0} g(x) = \inf\limits_{r>0} \sup\limits_{x\in B(x_0,r) \setminus \{x_0\}} \ g(x)$$. Then let $\delta= \inf\limits_{r>0} \sup\limits_{x\in B(x_0,r) \setminus \{x_0\}} \ g(x) - g(x_0)$, so we can choose that $0<r< \frac {\delta}{2}$. And choose $t_0 = g(x_0)+ \frac{\delta}{2}$.

Then we know $\exists (t,x) \in B_r((t_0,x_0))$ s.t. $ g(x) > t$ no matter how small the $r$ is, which is a contradiction. Similarly, we can prove $h$ is upper semicontinuous.

**Q1.** However, I am not sure how to prove mathematically the existence of such a $(t,x)$, it's easy to visualize the result when $W \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

**Q2.** And I am stuck on the second part.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a homework-type question, not research level, so not suitable for this site.  Flagged for migration to Math.SE.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry I didn't know that and thanks for the migration. Any chance you could help me with this problem? Thanks